# MySQL Order by month in specific order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a list of month in database. In query output I would like to Order by month But in very specific order.
('DEC', 'JUL', 'MAR', 'OCT,' 'MAY', 'JUN', 'FEB', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'APR', 'NOV', 'JAN')
Something like:

```
Select month from month_table
Order by month
```

How to specify customized Order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use the `field()` function:

```
order by field(month, 'DEC', 'JUL', 'MAR', 'OCT,' 'MAY', 'JUN', 'FEB', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'APR', 'NOV', 'JAN')
```